# I want to change a state via switch function but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, framer-motion

I'm trying to change a state from a useEffect and I'm using useScroll from framer motion to trace my y axis position on the webpage, then change a state based on that. As you can see I wrote some codes to make some other states true or false but when I want to change a state with a switch in the same useEffect and with same logic, it doesn't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
        return scrollY.onChange((latest) => {
            latest > 50 ? setScrollMoved(true) : setScrollMoved(false);
            latest > 399 ? setDevelopmentShow(true) : setDevelopmentShow(false);
            latest > 999 ? setBrandingShow(true) : setBrandingShow(false);
            latest > 1599 ? setDesignShow(true) : setDesignShow(false);
            switch (latest) {
                case latest > 399:
                    setLine("develop");
                case 1599 > latest > 399:
                    setLine("brand");
                case 2100 > latest > 1599:
                    setLine("brand");
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change my syntax a bit and write it with &&.

Comment: Please add the modified code in your awnser as it may help others in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can return inside of switch's case for example

```
switch (latest) {
                case latest > 399:
                    return setLine("develop");
                case 1599 > latest > 399:
                    return setLine("brand");
                case 2100 > latest > 1599:
                    return setLine("brand");
            }
```